# WF 4 Workflowservice with State Machine

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine, correlation, workflowservice

I'm currently working on a project where we want to implement a WF4 state machine as a workflowservice.  The fundamentals seem to make sense as we've used WF 3.5 in the past.  However one issue we've come across is that we'd like to be able to create an instance of the workflow at any of states (or at least more than just one of them).  Selecting the CanCreateInstance property on more than one Receive activity throws an exception.

I've played around with Maurice's suggestions on correlation from his [blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/04/28/workflow-receive-activity-and-message-correlation.aspx) but haven't been able to figure out how to apply that to a state machine.

Comment: Correlation should't be the problem here. That only comes into play when you send multiple requests to the same workflow instance. What exception are you getting?

Comment: I think I figured out the correlation issue I was seeing before.  Here is the exception I'm getting now:

Unhandled exception Operation 'Operation2|TestEventsService' on service instance with identifier 'd37944be-e5b6-4574-91e5-8044d980f0b6' cannot be performed at this time. Please ensure that the operations are performed in the correct order and that the binding in use provides ordered delivery guarantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a sample that might help you [Windows Workflow Foundation (WF4) - Silverlight / State Machine Workflow Service](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-f2c91fd7)

Comment: Thanks Ron (and Maurice too).  Correlation wasn't the problem. I looked at the WF4 State machine workflow service example you suggested and was able to figure it out.  The main problem was that I didn't have my initial receive activity in a transition out of the initial state.  I also was using Correlation Initializer instead of Correlates On.  Once I got the right combination of settings my workflow service started working as expected.